# Which CSS attribute should I move to rewind a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a form with a time element and a button. I would like to move the button to the bottom but not maximum of the bottom. Which CSS attribute should I modify ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Title">
    <link rel="icon" href="ressources/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary w-100 justify-content-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="navbar-brand">
            TEXT
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <center><b><label for="heure">This is a label</label></b></center>
    <center><form method="post" action="myaction.php" role="form" id="formulaire" style="padding: 70px;">
      <input type="time" id="heure" name="heure">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="valider" name="valider" type="submit" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:40%;"></button>
    </form></center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a missing div tag closure in your nav element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you made I just apply the css to your button more clearly in css and adjust center:

```css
#valider{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Title">
    <link rel="icon" href="ressources/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary w-100 justify-content-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="navbar-brand">
            TEXT
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <center><b><label for="heure">This is a label</label></b></center>
    <center><form method="post" action="myaction.php" role="form" id="formulaire" style="padding: 70px;">
      <input type="time" id="heure" name="heure">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="valider" name="valider" type="submit" style=""></button>
    </form></center>
  </body>
</html>
```